# Error org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I am facing a weird problem in one of my dev environments. Installed a new mysql 5.5 server and when running my spring/hibernate application, I encounter this error.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:393) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.getHibernateType(CustomLoader.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(CustomLoader.java:508) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:524) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1817) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:312) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1722) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar:3.4.0.GA]
... 79 common frames omitted
```

Here is the query that fails:

```
select count(e.event), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT e.event), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT e.eventid) , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT e.ttid), e.mmth, e.absq, e.year, e.mfnmm, e.retls, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT e.bbn),  e.bplk, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT e.ppd), e.sgm, e.sz, e.fm, e.ppk, e.pkg, e.mch, e.md, e.sw,e.ew,ROUND(sum(e.vol),2),ROUND(sum(e.is),2),ROUND(sum(e.iv),2),ROUND(sum(e.pbv),2),ROUND(sum(e.pbvo),2),ROUND(sum(e.upbva),2), ROUND(sum(e.unpbvo),2),ROUND(sum(e.cv),2), ROUND(sum(e.cva),2),   ROUND(sum(e.chv),2), ROUND(sum(e.chl),2) from s_test_mt e where  e.event is not null and e.event <> ''   and  e.mfnmm in ('Kern') group by e.mfnmm, e.retls, e.mch, e.ppk, e.fm, e.sw, e.ew order by e.ttid asc
```

I am using the following configuration in spring:

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
```

The exception occurs only when running a native query using hibernate. Also it runs fine on a different dev environment and production (typical eh !). Could it be caused by character-set of schema/table etc ?

I am using hibernate 3.3, and spring 3, and using entitymanager to access mysql innodb version 5.5.37

Any pointers as to where to start looking would be appreciated.

Comment: I managed to work around the problem for now by upgrading my hibernate to 3.5.5-Final . Still havent found the root cause

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I didn't provide an entity type to the SQLQuery as per:

```
 Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
"select * from stock s where s.activeStock = true")
.addEntity(Stock.class);
List result = query.list();
```

Thanks to mkyong (http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/)